# Is it possible to write an "insert into" statement for a single column table?

Tags: t-sql

Here's the caveat...

If you have a table that has a single column and that column happens to be an `identity` column with `identity_insert` turned **OFF**, is it still possible to write a T-SQL insert statement for this table?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sure

use `insert TableName default values`

example

```
create table Test (id int identity not null)


insert Test default values

select * from Test
```